# Given that $a | bc + b + c, b | ca + c + a$ and $c | ab + a + b$, prove that at least one of $a, b, c$ is not prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c$ be distinct integers. Given that $a | bc + b + c, b | ca + c + a$
> and $c | ab + a + b$, prove that at least one of $a, b, c$ is not prime.

WLOG $3\le a<b<c$ and suppose all are primes. Now if $bc+b+c=a\cdot\alpha $, then we get $(b+1)(c+1)=a\alpha +1$, so $\alpha $ is odd. Similarly for others.

Then I couldn't proceed much.

For $a=2$ , then it's not possible since $a=\text{even}| bc+c+b=\text{odd}$

I saw this  [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165070/807973), but that isn't the way I am doing. Can anyone give hints for this path?

Comment: I don't get what your path is. Do you intend on doing casework for every prime? I don't think that's a good way to go...

Comment: @DonThousand   actually I am supposed to use factorization method to solve this, the solution I linked was using bound.

Comment: $(b+1)(c+1)\equiv 1 \mod a$. $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\equiv 1 \mod abc$. $abc + \sum ab + \sum a \equiv 0 \mod abc$. That solution uses factorization too?

Comment: @SunainaPati You can leave this question as is. Maybe somebody with an innovative idea writes a solution without using bounds.

Comment: The approach I tried was to make the substitutions $a=2n_1+1$,$b=2n_2+1$ and $c=2n_3+1$. Then as per your divisibility conditions, make three equations, the right hand side of which are integers $x,y,z$. The next step which I have not quite got to is to show that for any naturals $x,y,z$ solving the system of equations in $n_1,n_2,n_3$  has solutions that are algebraic irrationals (not integers) this demonstates that $a,b,c$ cannot all be odd, therefore at least one must be even, and provided you can then show the case of one of them being equal to 2 fails,  conclude  at least one non prime

Comment: sorry just non integer there, rational non integer solutions are possible

Comment: and the equations to be constructed are $\frac{bc + b + c}{a}=x,\frac{ca + c + a}{b}=y,\frac{ab + a + b}{c}=z$ with the aforementioned substitutions

Comment: Sorry again my phrasing was not clear, it suffices to show that solving the system of equations in $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ will always contain at least one non integer solution.